# firebase.goOffline() to prevent connections

Tags: firebase, connection

I'm a teacher and our school just bought Chromebooks for every student. I wrote a typing program with the thought of having the students at my school use it, but I realized that would be 600 connections if all the teachers in the school typed at the same time.

I have a typing program where Firebase is used as a traditional database. The only time the Firebase receives a change is when users login or when they pass a typing test to update their profile as having passed the lesson.

Looking for a solution, I looked at the [Firebase.goOffline](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/gooffline.html) method, and it seemed I should be able to have the students login, go offline, and then [Firebase.goOnline()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/goonline.html) after they pass the test and then update their information to the database, and immediately go offline again. Would this be appropriate or am I missing something?

If this is a poor question, I apologize, but I wanted to ask before a few dozen students tomorrow lost all of their typing work because I changed the code on them inappropriately.

Comment: Hi Chance, sounds like a cool program! Calling `goOffline` and `goOnline` in that manner would indeed be a way to reduce the concurrent connections. But you might want to take a wait-and-see approach, since most users tend to highly overestimate the number of concurrent users they'll have. Also keep in mind that (on a paid plan) Firebase bills at the 95th percentile, so an occasional spike in the number of concurrent users should not impact your bill.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll see how it goes and if it gets high, I switch up the code a bit

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you please explain in a bit detail, what 95th percentile mean on the billing reference?