# Firebase connection count with angular bindings?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I've read quite a few posts (including the firebase.com website) on Firebase connections. The website says that one connection is equivalent to approximately 1400 visiting users per month. And this makes sense to me given a scenario where the client makes a quick connection to the Firebase server, pulls down some data, and then closes the connection. However, if I'm using angular bindings (via angularfire), wouldn't each client visit (in the event the user stays on the site for a period of time) be a connection? In this example having 100 users (each of which is making use of firebase angular bindings) connecting to the site at the same time would be 100 connections. If I opted not to use angular bindings, that number could be (in a theoretical sense) 0 if all the clients already made their requests for data and were just idling.

Do I understand this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularFire is built on top of Firebase's regular JavaScript/Web SDK. The connection count is fundamentally the same between them: if a 100 users are using your application at the same time and you are synchronizing data for each of them, you will have 100 concurrent connections at that time.

The statement that one concurrent connection is the equivalent of about 1400 visits per month is based on the extensive experience that the Firebase people have with how long the average connection lasts. As [Andrew Lee stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app/14307743#14307743): most developers vastly over-estimate the number of concurrent connections they will have.

As said: AngularFire fundamentally behaves the same as Firebase's JavaScript API (because it is built on top of that). Both libraries keep an open connection for a user, so that they can synchronize any changes that occur between the connected users. You can manually drop such a connection by calling `goOffLine` and then re-instate it with `goOnline`. Whether that is a good approach is largely dependent on the type of application you're building.

Two examples:

- There recently was [someone who was building a word game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334223/firebase-gooffline-to-prevent-connections). He used Firebase to store the final score for each game. In his case explicitly managing the connections makes sense, because the connection is only needed for a relatively short time when compared to the time the application is active.
- The "hello world" for Firebase programming is a [chat application](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/). In such an application it doesn't make a lot of sense to manage the connections yourself. So briefly connect every 15 seconds and then disconnect again. If you do this, you're essentially reverting to polling for updates. Doing so will lose you one of the bigger benefits of using Firebase: it automatically synchronizes data to connected clients.

So only you can decide whether explicit connection management is best for you application. I'd recommend starting without it (it's simpler) and first testing your application on a smaller scale to see how actual usage holds up to your expectation.